# Kernel Density Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, kernel-density

I have 3 point feature classes (test30, test90, test180) in a scratch.gdb. I would like to create a kernel density raster for each dataset. I would like the output of the kernel density raster to be saved in the scratch.gdb.

The error I am receiving is ERROR 010093: Output raster format UNKNOWN is unsupported. Can I save a kernel density raster to a File Geodatabase?

I am new to python and functions, so I may have some of this logic written incorrectly.

ArcDesktop 10.3.1

```
import os, sys, re, shutil
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
import arceditor


cwd = os.getcwd()

scratchGDB = r'C:\Users\test\scratch.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = scratchGDB
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


# kenrnel density
def kernel_density(dataset):

    try:
        if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
            arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
        else:
            raise LicenseError


        kd = KernelDensity(dataset, population_field='NONE', cell_size=1000, search_radius=50000, area_unit_scale_factor='SQUARE_MILES')

        kd.save(scratchGDB)

    finally:
            arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")

kernel_density('test180')
kernel_density('test90')
kernel_density('test30')
```

Comment: Two things I would check: The `KernelDensity` didn't run successfully and outputs something strange, I'm not sure how to check that. Also, you are saving in your GDB without specifying a name for your output data, I think it should be something like `kd.save(scratchGDB+"\\"+"kd_output")`

Comment: For any code snippets presented here please remove the try/except blocks that can mask errors, and then present precisely the test you run and any errors it outputs.

Comment: @chrki That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save the `KernelDensity` result in your GDB without specifying a name for your output data:

```python
kd.save(scratchGDB)
```

You have to add a name for your output layer, it may look like this:

```python
kd.save(scratchGDB + "\\" + dataset + "_kd")
# resulting name: C:\Users\test\scratch.gdb\test180_kd
```